# Two examples for projective resolutions for finite dimensional algebras

Tags: representation-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $A=KQ/I$ be a finite dimensional quiver algebra with admissible ideal $I$.
I search for two examples of the following kind.

> a) $M$ is an indecomposable $A$ module of infinite projective dimension such that there exists an $i$ such that $\Omega^i(M)$ has an indecomposable direct summand $N$ with $Ext_A^i(M,N)=0$ (note that $Ext_A^i(M,\Omega^i(M)) \neq 0$).

> b) $M$ is an indecomposable $A$ module with a minimal projective resolution $(P_i)$ with maps $f_i: P_i \rightarrow P_{i-1}$ such that $P_{i-1}$ has a direct summand $X$ such that the canonical composition $\pi f_i : P_i \rightarrow P_{i-1} \rightarrow X$ is zero where $\pi$ is the projection $P_{i-1} \rightarrow X$.

Comment: Isn’t the simple module at vertex 2 for the quiver $1 \leftarrow2\rightarrow 3\rightarrow4$ with radical square zero a counterexample for (b)?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks. I think that is correct. The last term $P_2$ has even $Hom(P_2,X)=0$ for a direct summand $X$ of $P_1$ with $X$ being the first simple module. If you want you can post it as an answer. It would also be interesting to see an example where this does not happen at the last term but somewhere before.

Comment: @JeremyRickard If you do not want to make this an answer, is it OK when I delete this question here and post question a) on mathoverflow?

Comment: I think I can answer to (a) as well, so I've posted both.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no example satisfying (a).

Suppose $(P_\bullet,d_\bullet)$ is a minimal projective resolution of $M$, so that $\Omega^i(M)=\operatorname{im}d_i=\ker d_{i-1}=N\oplus N'$.

Then the composition of the obvious maps $P_i\to\operatorname{im}d_i\to N$ is a map $\alpha:P_i\to N$ such that $\alpha d_{i+1}=0$ and so represents an element of $\operatorname{Ext}^i_A(M,N)$. If this element is zero, then $\alpha=hd_i$ for some $h:P_{i-1}\to N$, and so $h$ is a splitting of the inclusion of $N$ into $P_{i-1}$. So $N$ is a direct summand of $P_{i-1}$ that is contained in $\ker d_{i-1}$, contradicting minimality of the resolution.

For (b), an example is given by the quiver $1\xleftarrow{\alpha}2\xrightarrow{\beta}3\xrightarrow{\gamma}4$ with relation $\beta\gamma=0$. The minimal projective resolution of the simple module $S(2)$ at vertex $2$ is
$$0\to P(4)\to P(1)\oplus P(3)\to P(2)\to S(2)\to0$$
where $P(v)$ denotes the indecomposable projective module at vertex $v$. The composition $P(4)\to P(1)\oplus P(3)\to P(1)$ is zero.